# DevExpress XPO doesn't create right query

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have created an application in **express framework with blazor** in vs 2022.
I have used .Net 6.0 for application.

In this application i have two combo and it filter another combo like cascading way.

but my problem is i have created linq query but xpo generates different query and give us no output.

My linq query is below

```
  public Task<IQueryable<string>> GetCenterCodeAsync(IEnumerable<string> office = null)
        {
            
            var query = objectSpace.GetObjectsQuery<OfficeAndCenterGroups>();
            if (officeCode != null && officeCode.Count() > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(t => officeCode.Contains(t.OfficeCode.ToString()));
            }
            
            return Task.FromResult(
                query.Select(t =>
                         t.CenterCode
                   ).Distinct().AsQueryable());

        }
```

And its generated SQL query is below

```
exec sp_executesql N'select N0."CenterCode" from "dbo"."OfficeAndCenterGroups" N0
where (N0."GCRecord" is null and Cast((N0."OfficeCode") as nvarchar(max)) in (@p0))
group by N0."CenterCode"',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'04'
```

and its different than as i want

```
SELECT distinct CenterCode 
FROM dbo.OfficeAndCenterGroups 
Where (OfficeCode) in (N'04') group by CenterCode
```

**Below query dose not give records because of cast in where clause.**

```
SELECT distinct CenterCode 
FROM dbo.OfficeAndCenterGroups 
Where CAST(OfficeCode as nvarchar) in (N'04') group by CenterCode
```

How can resolve this issue?

**My System Environment is:-**

Win 11

Visual Studio 2022

Blazor .Net 6.0

Comment: The only *substantive* difference is the `GCRecord is null` check; is that what you're referring to here? is that perhaps part of some discriminatior / etc config of the type?

Comment: Thank you Marc Gravell for very quick response but combine condition in where clause creates a problem even when i remove "GCRecord" condition from where clause also getting no records and its wrong SQL query, because unnecessary cast in where clause.

Comment: Below query dose not generate output but when i remove cast from where clause it give records.  
SELECT distinct CenterCode 
FROM dbo.OfficeAndCenterGroups 
Where CAST(OfficeCode as nvarchar) in (N'04') group by CenterCode

Comment: well, what is the type of `OfficeCode` in the database?

Comment: OfficeCode is integer (int) type in database.

Comment: then: why are you treating it as a string? *that* is the fundamental problem here; if it is an integer: *treat it as an integer throughout*

Comment: Yes, after changing the type it resolved Thanks